# How to convert selected pdf page with gm

Tags: node.js, pdf, image-processing, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am converting different images and pdf files with "gm" module for nodejs. Image types go successfully but when I want to convert PDF to image have problems. I need to covert only one selected page from pdf file to jpg/png. If I pass whole pdf file to "gm" it saves to image only first page, but I cannot find the way to save another page.

```
gm(file).toBuffer(format.toUpperCase(), 
       function (err, buffer) {
    // so in buffer now we have converted image
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: You need to split the PDF pages and pass each one to GM.

Comment: @BenFortune can you recommend some working module for this? spindrift produce error

Comment: did u get the soluton

Comment: What was the solution that you used?

Comment: Could anybody share the solution they've found?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`gm.selectFrame`](https://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html#selectframe) like this

```js
gm(file).selectFrame(0).toBuffer() // To get first page
gm(file).selectFrame(1).toBuffer() // To get second page
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
// for only first pdf page use:
gm(file, 'pdf.pdf[0]').toBuffer(...)
// for only second pdf page use:
gm(file, 'pdf.pdf[1]').toBuffer(...)
```

Answer (score -2):

There is [spindrift](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spindrift) for manipulating pdf (includes image conversion).

You can define your pdf using (You don't have you use all of the commands):

```
var pdf = spindrift('in.pdf')
   .pages(7, 24)
   .page(1)
   .even()
   .odd()
   .rotate(90)
   .compress()
   .uncompress()
   .crop(100, 100, 300, 200) // left, bottom, right, top
```

Later on convert to image:

```
// Use the 'index' property of an image element to extract an image: 
pdf.extractImageStream(0)
```

If you have to use gm, you can do what @Ben Fortune suggested in his comment and split the pdf first.

Comment: I tried this library, but how to create this "spindrift" from buffer?

Comment: Have you tried using your "file" variable with spindrift before using toBuffer?

Comment: Hm , I tried just without buffering (just opened and tried to save new file) and got error
`spawn: pdftk /var/www//temp/tt.pdf output -`

`events.js:72`
        `throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event``
           `   ^`
`Error: spawn ENOENT`
 `   at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)`
`    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)`

Comment: the double slash here are intended?
/var/www"//"temp/tt.pdf

Comment: no i just removed the whole path from there, actually is like /var/www/temp/tt.pdf

Comment: Have you tried 
var pdf = spindrift('/var/www/temp/tt.pdf')?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70714/discussion-between-or-guz-and-user755669).