# Graphicsmagick for Node not writing to the correct file when converting PDF

Tags: node.js, pdf, graphicsmagick

I'm creating a thumbnail from the first page of a PDF with the Node `gm` module.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var gm = require('gm');

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("cover.jpg");

// Create JPG from page 0 of the PDF
gm("file.pdf[0]").setFormat("jpg").write(writeStream, function(error){
    if (!error) {
        console.log("Finished saving JPG");
    }
});
```

There's two problems with the script.

1. It creates a file `cover.jpg`, but that file is empty (size 0) and can't be opened by any viewer.
2. It creates a file named `[object Object]` that is an image of the PDF's first page (this is what I want, but the wrong name).

Aside from doing some additional file system manipulation to rename the `[object Object]` file after generating it, is there something I can change in the way I am using `gm` and `fs` in this script to write the image directly to the `cover.jpg` file?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453823/how-to-convert-selected-pdf-page-with-gm) is similar to what I am asking, but there is no accepted working answer and I need to install yet another library to use it (undesirable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write` receives the file path as the first argument, not a write stream, therefore the method is converting the stream object into its string representation, that's why it saves a file named `[object Object]`.

You can just use `.write("cover.jpg")`, or if you want to use a write stream, you may use `.stream().pipe(writeStream)`.

Take a look at the [stream examples](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm#streams) of `gm`.